# How to map the selected data in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I can get the data from what i selected

```
  const onHandleSelectLocation = async (value) => {
    console.log(value)
    
  }
```

this is the data result from console.log

[image]

I am having a hard time getting the `Email` only, how can i achieve that? i've tried the `value.email` but it getting undefined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `value` shown in the log is *array of objects*, if you want to get the email, do the `map` instead

```
const onHandleSelectLocation = async (value) => {
  console.log(value);
  const emails = value.map(({ email }) => email);
  console.log(emails);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`value` is an `array` with `two objects`, that includes email, id and name. if you want to access one of those, you can use `map`. you can mapping in array and use what properties that you need from objects.

for example like this:

```
value.map => ( item => <div key={item.id}> {item.email} </div>)
```